# How to highlight the price when a candle crosses the previous candle which is closed above EMA100 line?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

I'm new to pine script and I am trying to figure out how to make an indicator highlighting:

Price when the current candle cross below the wick low of previous candle + previous candle should be completely detached (even the wick) above the EMA100 line

Please help anyone :)

I tried something like this but it doesn't work :(

`ema100 = ta.ema(close, 100)`
`emaGapBelow = high < ema100`
`emaGapAbove = low > ema100`
`entryCandle = close < emaGapAbove`

`plotshape(entryCandle)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pinescript the number in brackets is used to acces previous data.
For example to get the previous low, you use :

```
low[1]
```

For your code, you should try :

```
ema100 = ta.ema(close,100)
currentcrossbelow = close < low[1]
previousdetached = low[1] > ema100[1]

if currentcrossbelow and previousdetached
    // Here, your conditions are met
```

Comment: Thanks this helped but i also want to trigger an alert as soon as my current candle price (not close price) cuts below the low of previous candle. How do i do that sir?

Comment: Please ask a new question, so that we can answer